# Edit XML file in as3

Tags: android, xml, actionscript-3, flash

I am very new to actionscript3, so my apologies if this is a silly/poorly worded question.

I have seen other topics with similar titles to this one, but most of those want to create an XML in flash and then customise it, which is not exactly what I want.

Basically, I have created an android game where, when the user loses the game, I want them to be able to share their score on Facebook. I am using a prebuilt system, which I am not able to properly customise for reasons which are a little complicated to go into.

A .swf file loads into the game and displays a message from an XML file.

My final score saves to a variable in the form of a string when the game over screen loads.

The XML file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<details>
<appID>#########</appID>
<message>I just scored 'X' in 'Game'! Download the Android app here 'Y'</message>
</details>
```

What is the simplest way I can customise the XML to simply replace the 'X' with the following variable:

```
finalScore = addZero(minuteTimer) + ":" + addZero(secondTimer);
```

And make it display in the form it displays in the game, e.g. 01:29?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The following code assumes that the XML is stored in a variable called `shareXML`:

`shareXML.message[0] = shareXML.message[0].split("'X'").join(finalScore);`

EDIT to demonstrate loading an XML file:

```
var xmlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("yourxmlfile.xml"));
xmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXMLLoaded);
xmlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onXMLError);
function onXMLLoaded(event:Event):void
{
    var loader:URLLoader = event.target as URLLoader;

    // store the contents of the loaded XML file into your variable
    shareXML = new XML(loader.data);
}
function onXMLError(event:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    trace("there was an error loading the xml file");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The XML sits alongside the swf for the game (in the same folder). To store this in a variable, should I use a 'URLLoader' and/or a 'URLRequest'? And then maybe place the XML inside another variable once it has loaded? Apologies for my ignorance, I really am a newcomer to coding in general. And thanks again for answering my question.

Comment: @jamesmitchell2312 as you're on android, use `FileStream`: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html#open() in `WRITE` mode - it lets you save a file without opening a dialog. Be careful with security permissions - you might not be able to write to the application directory itself. In that case, you save your file to the user directory and load it from there, with a fallback to the xml beside your swf, if it doesn't exist